# httpHelpPageUrl in web.config not working

Tags: .net, wcf

I would like to replace the default help page url for me WCF service. According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.httphelppageurl%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) i should be able to set the HttpHelpPageUrl and HttpHelpPageEnabled attributes in web.config and i should be in business. Not working for me.

I'm using .net 4.0. I know my serviceBehavior is getting recognized because i get results if i make other changes such as putting httpHelpPageEnabled="false".

This is my web.config:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageUrl="~/info.html" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

This is the page i would like to replace:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a/) `httpHelpPageUrl` lets you move the default WCF help page to another location. So if you want to provide your custom page you should make a enpoint providing handling your HTML.

More details (including sample code) is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a/)

Comment: Interesting (+1) so the value of `httpHelpPageURL` should not contain the URL of a page i made, rather, it's the value of the endpoint I want it to respond to? I'll give this a shot and give credit as soon as i verify. Thanks.